# Reload image without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

Javascript:

```
function atualiza() {
  document.getElementById('badge').innerHTML = location.reload();
}
```

I know the "location.reload()" will refresh the page...

HTML:

```
<img id="badge" src="<?php echo $cms_url; ?>/imaging/badge.php?badge=$mygroup['badge']; ?>" />
```

I need to freshed the `src=""` or `<img />` without refreshing the page.

Comment: Why are you using an element as an attribute's value?

Comment: I don't know how can I do it... The right would be a <div> before <img>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your `img` tag to this:

```
<img id="badge" src="$cms_url/imaging/badge.php?badge=$mygroup['badge']; ?>">/imaging/badge.php?badge=<?php echo $mygroup['badge']; ?>" />
```

Then you can use below code to change your image source on click of a button, anchor or whatever:

```
document.getElementById("badge").src="new image src here";
```

You can use jQuery as well:

```
$("#badge").attr("src", "new image src here");
```

Comment: what if the image is going to use the same src and the server will provide another image

Answer (score 21):

See this: [Updating a picture without page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509981/updating-a-picture-without-page-reload)

```
document.getElementById('yourimage').src = "url/of/image.jpg?random="+new Date().getTime();
```

anyways, this was copied off that thread and apparently it should reload the image.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the javascript i wrote is usefull for someone who reads this question. it ads a timestamp to every image to break the browser cache:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    function replaceSrc()
    {

        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            var dt = new Date();
            var img = images[i];

            if(img.src.length >= 0 & img.id != 'idImageNoTimestamp')
            {
                img.src = img.src + "?" + dt.getTime();
                //javascript:alert(document.lastModified);
            }
        }
    }
    replaceSrc();
      </script>
```

you can exclude some images by using the id attribute. I used it to exclude Google static maps images. if you don't need it, remove:

```
 & img.id != 'idImageNoTimestamp'
```

Comment: I like this, but if you want this in a page that reloads only parts it needs to be `img.src = img.src.split("?")[0] + "?" + dt.getTime();`

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJs, we can add directly in html file like this:

**Html:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1"><div ng-repeat="img in images"> <img ng-src="{{img.image}}?_={{generatingNewDate}}"></div></div>
```

Ctrl:
`$scope.generatingNewDate = new Date().getTime();`

You can have a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/k614L8tt/

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this?

```
<img id="badge" src="<img id="badge" src="$cms_url/imaging/badge.php?badge=$mygroup['badge']; ?>">/imaging/badge.php?badge=<?php echo $mygroup['badge']; ?>">
```

when you may do this

```
<img id="badge" src="<?php echo $cms_url. '/imaging/badge.php?badge='.$mygroup['badge']; ?>">
```

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer