# Choose new image from gallery and display it without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to change an image

I have user profiles with avatars.
I display image like this:

```
<img src="'images/<?=$default_image_data['image_name']?>" width=200 height=150>
```

What do I need?
I want to choose new image from modal(?) list, update database and display new assigned image without page reload.

1. Click buton "change image"
2. Now I want to see modal with small thumbnails of images(like 150x100)
3. I want to click on image to choose, next ajax-post to update row/assign new image to profile id
4. on ajax success I want to display new image without page reload

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: something like [this as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21322925)

Comment: probably good solution for point 4. on ajax success: change image source, but how to code js for point 2 and 3? Any working examples?