# Can Bootstrap carousel be forced to reload images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

My page has a bootstrap carousel that shows images from 12 security cameras.

I've set up an app on my camera server that does an image grab every 10 seconds and places it in a folder on my webserver.  The images always have the same names so - for instance - I'll have files:

```
north_parking.jpg
south_parking.jpg
front_door.jpg
side_door.jpg
```

The point being that the names don't change.

My carousel loads the images and works fine.  But it caches them so they don't update - even after 10 minutes I'll still see the same images in the carousel even though the files have changed many times since.

Is there a way to force the carousel to reload the images? I would prefer not to refresh the entire page - just the carousel images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a picture without page reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509981/updating-a-picture-without-page-reload)

Comment: The accepted answer is about the OP's Perl code but there are two answers with JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  There are, indeed, js solutions to be had there.